# CreateAsyncThunk function not returning fetched data after being Dispatched to React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, redux

I just started using redux.

In this project, I am using redux toolkit's createAsyncThunk to fetch data from firestore db inside a slice called orderSlice.

I am trying to loop through the data returned and display them on my orders component.

I am having issues figuring out what the issue is on this code

Here's my createAsyncThunk

```
//getting all orders from the database
export const getOrders = createAsyncThunk(
    'orders/getOrders',
    async(id = null, {rejectWithValue}) => {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "transactions"));
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        var data = doc.data(); 
        data = ({...data, id: doc.id})
        return data // console.log(data) returns my data 
})
}'
)
```

When I console.log(data), I get my data back, which means the fetch request is working...

But the fetched orders are not passed to my component to be looped through.

Here's my extraReducer

```
 [getOrders.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.orders = action.payload
          }
        }
```

Here's my export

```
export const selectAllOrders = (state) => state.orders;
```

and my useSelector declaration

```
const orders = useSelector(selectAllOrders)
```

With getOrders imported from the orderSlice into the component, here's my useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getOrders())
    }, [dispatch])
```

This is where I am mapping through my fetched orders

```
{orders?.map(order => (
          <article key={order.id}>
            <p onClick={() => navigate(`/order/${order.id}`)}>{order.currency}{order.toRecieveAmount}{order.resellerName}</p>
            within the next 24 hours</small>
            <span>Transaction Status: {order.statusBuyer}</span>
          </article>
        )) }
```

What do you think I am doing wrong?

At what stage am I missing something?

Comment: You did not describe what is actually not working or what error you are getting.

Comment: You haven't shown where the `orders` variable is coming from.  Possibly your `useSelector` is not selecting the correct value from the state.  Like maybe you are using `useSelector(state => state.orders)` instead of `useSelector(state => state.someSlice.orders)`, or something like that.  Try looking in Redux Dev Tools to see if your state is getting updated in the store.

Comment: @LindaPaiste orders is from the useSelector and it’s like this orders = useSelector(selectAllOrders)

Comment: @LindaPaiste I just checked the dev tools, the state isn’t getting updated. It still remains an empty array